# Why GetAsyncKeyState not work on MS Excel

Tags: vb.net

I wrote simple program capture to witch key is pressed while running program. it works normally but it do not works on ms excel. i cant figure out where the problem. anyone can help? I'm new to programming.

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vkey As Integer) As Integer

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

Dim Result as integer
For i = 1 to 255
       Result = GetAsyncKeyState(i)
       If Result = -32767 then
             textbox1.text = Cstr(chr(i))
       End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper declaration of `GetAsyncKeyState` is:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function GetAsyncKeyState(ByVal vKey As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) _  
                                        As Short
End Function
```

`GetAsyncKeyState` doesnt work like that. You should check the most significant bit of the return value (which is short):

```
If (Result And &H8000) <> 0 then 'the key is pressed
    textbox1.text = Cstr(chr(i))
End If
```

You should also check if `Result` is `zero`

EDIT, the loop must be from `1 to 254` not 255! In timer tick:

```
Timer1.Enabled = False

Dim Result As Short
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 254
    Result = GetAsyncKeyState(CType(i, Keys))
    If (Result And &H8000) <> 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = CStr(Chr(i))
    End If
Next

Timer1.Enabled = True
```

valter

Comment: @user3545835 So the problem is elsewhere